# Change bootstrap datepicker date format on select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker on a textbox. The default format of the date when you select a date is mm/dd/yyyy. Now I want to change it to dd/mm/yyyy. How can I accomplish this. Right now I'm just initializing it just like this.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

What should I add to change its format?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

See http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
 });
```

Comment: Found this answer while searching google. Anyways, I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I'm not the OP, but I had the same problem. Now the format works good, but the starting date is 1901.

Comment: I found using YYYY/MM/DD format avoided all kinds of parsing errors when converting to and from a date in Postgres and back to the view.  Just a heads up to fellow Rails devs.

Answer (score 13):

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.4 and using the code:

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
 });
```

Output is: 16-07-2015

Note: only need "yy" for full year.

Answer (score 13):

As of 2016 I used datetimepicker like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#date_box').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
    });
});
```

Comment: What you wrote gives back the minutes and seconds. I think what you meant is: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'

Comment: there's nothing about time in the question

Answer (score 3):

If by ID:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

});
```

If by Class:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'

});
```

Answer (score 1):

File name : `bootstrap-datepicker.js` Line No : 41:

```
this.format = DPGlobal.parseFormat(options.format||this.element.data('date-format')||dates[this.language].format||'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Comment: This is a radical solution, however it's recommended to not change the source file directly, it's better to add some extra code to modify the result.Just like when you want to add extra css to bootstrap, you create new file to preserve the original code.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41921409/8401131) works for me

Open the file `bootstrap-datepicker.js`

Go to line 1399 and find `format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'`.

Now you can change the date format here.

Answer (score 0):

for me with bootstrap 4 datetime picker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)
format worked only with upper case:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
      {
        format: 'Y-m-d h:m:s'
     }
    );
 });`
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what mine looks like:

```
<input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control  date-picker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers are not helping out please make sure you are applying format property on the right object.

For DatePicker

```
$(function () {
    $('#date_box').datepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
    });
});
```

For Date And time Picker

```
$(function () {
    $('#date_box').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `format` did not work. Following code worked.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: new Date() // disabling past dates
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way:

Open the file `bootstrap-datepicker.js`

Go to line 1399 and find `format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'`.

Now you can change the date format here.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: This answer suggests changing the source of the plugin, which is never a good idea if you want to be able to update the plugin in the future. The accepted answer shows how to do it through the options that you pass to `datepicker()`.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using new jqueryui
above code will not help you
use this

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
```

Comment: This is much better off as a comment as this will not answer the OP.